# Android 9.0 - How to find if user has inserted a corrupted sd card?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)//corrupted -sd card
```

But whenever I insert a corrupted sd card, the status is always "mounted", is this approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by finding whether the inserted card is read-only or not, by traversing the /proc/mounts file and checking whether read_options of sdcard's mounted_directory is read-only or read-write.